# Linux: What causes static ARP entries to flush on link down

Tags: linux-networking, arp, iproute2

This is a question about a difference in networking behavior between *Debian Buster* (kernel 4.19.0-18) and *Debian Bullseye* (kernel 5.10.0-9). On Buster, proxy arp entries survive if the link on the interface goes down. On Bullseye they don't.

Situation: create a static proxy ARP entry on a specific interface:

```
ip neigh add proxy 1.2.3.5 dev eth0
```

I can verify that the entry exists:

```
ip neigh show proxy
```

Now, if the link on that interface goes down and comes back up again, on Buster the proxy arp entries are still there, on Bullseye they are gone.

I would like to know *the reason behind this difference*. Is it a kernel feature? Is it udev that does this? Is there a sysctl setting governing this?

Could someone point me in the right direction? If you know how to create static ARP entries on Bullseye / kernel 5.10 that would be even better.

Note that I'm using sysvinit, not systemd. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the history of the changes related to this issue:

- [2018-10-12 09:47:39 -0700](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/netdev/net-next.git/commit/?id=859bd2ef1fc1110a8031b967ee656c53a6260a76)

  > net: Evict neighbor entries on carrier down

  is committed on netdev -next tree: this is responsible of removing neighbor entries when a link gets a carrier down, with a rationale in the commit message.
- [2018-10-22 07:47:45 +0100](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tag/?h=v4.19)

  kernel v4.19 is released.

  This still doesn't include the commit from the netdev -next branch.
- [2018-10-24 06:47:44 +0100](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=v4.20&id=50b825d7e87f4cff7070df6eb26390152bb29537)

  Merge of Davem's pull request including the previous neighbor change is merged in linux master thus to be included in linux [v4.20](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tag/?h=v4.20) once released.

fast forward...

- [2021-11-01 19:57:14 -0700](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fcdb44d08a95003c3d040aecdee286156ec6f34e) + [2021-11-01 19:57:17 -0700](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=52fa3ee0cce60a04739f4a5ca1c9d5c2a8ee1578)

  > net: arp: introduce `arp_evict_nocarrier` sysctl parameter

  > This change introduces a new sysctl parameter, `arp_evict_nocarrier`.
  > When set (default) the ARP cache will be cleared on a `NOCARRIER` event.
  > This new option has been defaulted to '1' which maintains existing
  > behavior.
  > [...]

So you likely will have to wait for kernel >= 5.16 in bullseye-backports to get the old behavior back by doing then for example:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_evict_nocarrier=0
```

or wait that some later adjustment makes *proxy* entries behave like permanent entries (which get specific code to not be affected on a carrier down event).

---

About the second question "how to create static ARP entries", here's the method to add a static entry for 192.0.2.2 with MAC address 12:34:56:78:9a:bc on interface *eth0*, using the `replace` keyword instead of the `add` keyword which could randomly return an `RTNETLINK answers: File exists error` (or of `change` which would suffer from the opposite):

```
ip neigh replace 192.0.2.2 dev eth0 lladdr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc nud permanent
```